# Zip with amazon lambda. Why is it slow?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to get performant file zipping using amazon lambda with s3 buckets. The files I want to zip are on a bucket. The lambda I'm testing is supposed to get file paths and create a `zip` from them on the same bucket.

I'm using this library https://github.com/orangewise/s3-zip and I'm testing it exactly as it is on this example: https://github.com/orangewise/s3-zip/blob/master/aws_lambda.md

I just run a test that gives paths of two files as an input. One of them has 2 MB and the second 58 KB and they are of `docx` and `doc` type.
The test event looks like this:

```
{
     "region": "eu-west-1",
     "bucket": "bucket_name",
     "folder": "folder_name/",
     "files": [
         "file1.doc",
         "file2.docx"
     ],
   "zipFileName": "test.zip"
 }
```

I got this test report

```
START RequestId: xxx Version: $LATEST
2016-07-26T20:40:02.084Z    xxx    event { 
  region: 'eu-west-1',
  bucket: 'bucket_name',
  folder: 'folder_name/',
  files: [ 'file1.doc', 'file2.docx' ],
  zipFileName: 'test.zip' }
2016-07-26T20:40:02.765Z    xxx    append to zip file1.doc
2016-07-26T20:40:04.364Z    xxx    append to zip file2.docx
2016-07-26T20:40:04.364Z    xxx    end -> finalize
2016-07-26T20:40:07.066Z    xxx    { loaded: 3011247,
  total: 3011247,
  part: 1,
  key: 'folder_name/test.zip' }
2016-07-26T20:40:08.232Z    xxx    { ETag: '"xyz"',
  Location: 'https://bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/folder_name/test.zip',
  key: 'folder_name/test.zip',
  Key: 'folder_name/test.zip',
  Bucket: 'bucket_name' }
END RequestId: xxx
REPORT RequestId: xxx    Duration: 6149.09 ms    Billed Duration: 6200 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB    Max Memory Used: 75 MB
```

This means that amazon lambda needs over 6 seconds to make the task. It seems to be slow. Can I make it faster? I already tried with giving the lambda more memory without any result.

What might be important I uploaded the lambda as a zip, because I needed the node_modules dependencies for this library I'm using.

Comment: I think I found the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36983138/are-there-any-performance-functionality-differences-for-aws-lambda-functions-wri

Comment: I repeated the test for only one small file and got the result in 4 seconds. I it this confirms that the problem is with starting the lambda function.

Comment: Be sure to also try much larger memory sizes.  Increasing the memory size increases speed dramatically, since the garbage collection doesn't need to run as often (or at all).  This is especially true for Java.  Of course, you also get proportionally more CPU time with larger memory, so it's a double win.

As you've seen, be sure to run any test multiple times to compare cold start with warm.